# Cannot create Angular CLI project in WebStorm

Tags: angular, webstorm

Today, I'm trying to create an `Angular-CLI` project from [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/). However, I got an error message as shown in the screenshot:

[image: Error in creating project]

After searching a bit on Google, I found out that the function `ng init` has been removed ([change log](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#100-beta32-2017-02-17)). I think we should use `ng new` instead.

How can we configure WebStorm to use `ng new`? Or what is an alternative way to create an `Angular-CLI` project in WebStorm?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: why don't you just create the project using the command line, and then use webstorm to open the resulting folder?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing now. But I just want to make use of WebStorm :)